# Connection between Var(X), Var(Y) and E(XY)

Tags: probability, variance

What I know is that:
$$Var(X), Var(Y) < \infty$$
I am to prove the following thesis:
$$E(XY) < \infty$$
I tried to solve the problem using this dependence:
$$
\begin{split}
\infty &> Var(X) + Var(Y) \\
       &= Var(X + Y) + 2Cov(X, Y) \\
       &= Var(X + Y) + 2\left(E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)\right)
\end{split}
$$
I don't know if it's a good attempt however and if it is I don't know how to finish the proof.

  -

---

### Edit

So after some calculations I do have:
$$E\big((X+Y)^2 \big) - E(X+Y)^2 + 2\big(E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) \big) \\
= E(X^2)+2E(XY)+E(Y^2) -E(X)^2 -2E(X)E(Y) -E(Y)^2 +2E(XY) - 2E(X)E(Y) \\
= E(X^2)+4E(XY)+E(Y^2) -E(X)^2 -4E(X)E(Y) -E(Y)^2 \\
= E(X^2)+4E(XY)+E(Y^2) - \big( E(X)^2 +4E(X)E(Y) +E(Y)^2\big)$$
And I can use the inequality given in the post but it don't simplify anything. Where can I go from here?

Comment: $Var(X+Y)=E((X+Y)^2)-E(X+Y)^2$ might help you.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Thank you! I managed to solve the problem

Comment: You could also possibly apply the Cauchy Schwartz inequality to prove the claim.

Comment: My answer was a hint from where to start, it wasn't a hint on how to complete your existing attempt of a proof. If you think about it, the hint given immediately leads to the required result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

For any two real numbers $a$ and $b$,

$$|ab|\leq\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$$

Note that $V(X)$ finite implies $E(X^2)$ is finite.

Comment: Why $V(X) < \infty \rightarrow E(X^2) < \infty$?

Comment: Think of how $V$ is defined

Comment: @Hendrra Because $V(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$ whenever the expectations exist. The l.h.s is finite thus implies that both $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$ are finite.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks so much!

Comment: If I know that $E(X), E(X^2)$ are finite I don't have to use the inequality above, do I?

Comment: @Hendrra You would have to if you want to show that expectation of $XY$ is finite. Why else would I suggest using it?

Comment: @StubbornAtom So I must have been wrong with my calculations. In a moment I'll edit my post and I'd appreciate your looking at it.